# PHP combine variables

Tags: php, variables

I have the following code:

```
session_start();
$error_fname = $_SESSION['error_fname'];
$error_lname = $_SESSION['error_lname'];
$error_email = $_SESSION['error_email'];
$error_email_invalid = $_SESSION['error_email_invalid'];

$error = array(
    'fname' => $error_fname,
    'lname' => $error_lname,
    'email' => $error_email,
    'email_invalid' => $error_email_invalid);
```

This is on top of the page, and down at my contact form, the following code is placed:

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
```

For some reason, when I trigger an error, the page refreshes, and prints out the following:

[image: Array]

How can I make it so one variable ($error) displays all of the possible errors?

The _SESSION variables are defined in the following file:
/assets/redir/contact.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['error_fname'] = " ";
$_SESSION['error_lname'] = " ";
$_SESSION['error_email'] = " ";
$_SESSION['error_email_invalid'] = " ";

if($_POST['fname']){
if($_POST['lname']){
if($_POST['email']){
if (strstr($_POST['email'], '@') && strstr($_POST['email'], '.')) {

mail('', 'Nieuw bericht van je website!', strip_tags($_POST['message']));

header('Location: ../../index.php');

}else
$_SESSION['error_email_invalid'] = "<div class='mssg mssg_error'>Het ingevoerde e-mail adres is niet correct.</div>";header('Location: ../../index.php');
}else
$_SESSION['error_email'] = "<div class='mssg mssg_error'>Je e-mail adres is verplicht</div>";header('Location: ../../index.php');
}else
$_SESSION['error_lname'] = "<div class='mssg mssg_error'>Je achternaam is verplicht</div>";header('Location: ../../index.php');

}else
$_SESSION['error_fname'] = "<div class='mssg mssg_error'>Je voornaam is verplicht</div>";header('Location: ../../index.php');

?>
```

When using `var_dump($error);` I get the following:

[image: Var Dump]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `<?php echo $error['fname']; ?>` because `$error` is an array

Comment: Well, a ugly way of doing it would be to `<?php echo implode(', ',$error); ?>`

Comment: echo does not print array so use print_r($error);

Comment: I understand I didn't formulate my question right. I have updated it. In case any questions remain, please feel free to ask them!

Answer (score 0):

`$error` is array so you need to iterate by this and display each element separately:

```
foreach ($error as $er) {
    if (!empty($er)) {
       echo $er;
       break; //to leave for first error
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that works. But now the errors keep adding up. I am looking for a solution that displays only one message in a specific order. Like this:

1. first name
2. last name
3. email
4. Correct email

Comment: I've updated my answer and added `break` to leave loop when first error appeard

Comment: Updated the question, so it is more clear what is going on.

Comment: Still I think my code is doing what you want so show me what exactly contains `$error`. Do `var_dump($error);` instead of your old echo.

Comment: Edited the question once more

Comment: Right. So if I understand you well, you want to display only one of error and then stop. That what is doing my script. If not, if you want sth different, please explain me once more what you want because probably I misunderstand you

Comment: A user enters in the fields, but when he (or she) forgets one, I want to display an error on index.php. But as a matter of fact, the php script is made in contact.php. When a user enters my site by going to the URL, I don't want any messages displayed. And when the send was a succes, I want to display a succes message. But only when submit is clicked ofcourse. But if($_POST['submit_btn']){#code...} wouldn't work here, as there is a different file involved. If you have any questions, please ask! Thanks for the help.

Comment: So what display for you my script? It should display one error when user will have error. Does it displayed? If yes, it means I still do not understand what you want :(

Comment: When a user generates an error in one of the if statements in contact.php, I want a _SESSION() variable to carry the error to my index.php. There I want only then and there to have the error displayed. So:

1. The user generates an error in an if() statement in contact.php

2. The error gets in a _SESSION() variable, so I can get it over to index.php

3. The error is displayed on a specific place (where it is right now).